# Error while creating the public and private DNS using threads on Azure: com.microsoft.azure.CloudException: Status code 409

Tags: java, multithreading, azure, azure-devops, dns

I am trying to create the private and public DNS records on Azure using Java, for which I have used the `com.microsoft.azure.management.privatedns.v2018_09_01.implementation.privatednsManager` for creating the **Private DNS** record and

`com.microsoft.azure.management.dns.implementation.DnsZoneManager` for creating the **Public DNS** record.

There are **5 different threads** trying to create the records through the code.

But getting the error as:

```
com.microsoft.azure.CloudException: Status code 409, {\"code\":\"Conflict\",\"message\":\"Another operation is pending for requested object\"}
```

Is there anything wrong with creating the DNS records using threads?
Is there ay other way we can achieve creating the DNS records using threads?